# Is adding a dummy value to the entire dataset correct way to deal with zero inflated Bray-Curtis Index in R (vegan/ Biodiversity) package?

Tags: r, vegan

I'm trying to calculate the "cproj" i.e. the projection values of each species using `add.spec.score` package in BiodiveristyR. My datapoints however are zero inflated. I calculate the BrayCurtis index but it will not let me use the cmdscale since the BC scores generate NANs in the data set. However, if I add a dummy variable "1" to my entire dataset, the problem dissapears. However, I'm sure if this is the correct way to deal with this. Is there something else in the package which will allow me to deal with this type of error?

```
library(vegan)
library(BiodiversityR)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(111)
sp1 <- sample(0:1,72, replace = TRUE)
sp2 <- sample(0:1,72, replace = TRUE)
sp3 <- sample(0:1,72, replace = TRUE)
sp4 <- sample(0:1,72, replace = TRUE)

wide.site <- data.frame(sp1, sp2, sp3, sp4)

wide.site <- wide.site + 1 #If I don't add 1 to this data, the cmdscale in third line from here will not work 

species.db <- vegdist(wide.site, method = "bray")
species.db <- vegdist(wide.site, method = "bray", upper = TRUE, diag = TRUE)
species.pcoa <- cmdscale(species.db, eig = TRUE, k = 3)

fish <- wide.site

speciesREL <- fish
for(i in 1:nrow(fish)){
  speciesREL[i, ] = fish[i, ] / sum(fish[i, ])
}

species.pcoa <- BiodiversityR::add.spec.scores(species.pcoa, speciesREL, method = "pcoa.scores")
species.pcoa$cproj
```

Comment: @Gwen B. Sorry, this should be a comment but I don't have enough reputation to comment. Thus, to expand on Gwen B.'s reply: I understood the Clarke et al. 2006 paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S002209810500599X as adding a new "species", i.e. new variable (with 1 everywhere), and not just adding a value to all species. That does not help though, if - as in my case - samples have no species at all, i.e. are 0 throughout. I do want to retain such samples, even if they all fall into one point in any ordination. But I can artificially draw those points apart from each ot

Answer (score 2):

You have several rows in your data set that have only zeros. You get a warning of these:

```
Warning messages:
1: In vegdist(wide.site, method = "bray") :
  you have empty rows: their dissimilarities may be meaningless in method “bray”
```

Because you have several all-zero rows, you will end up with Bray-Curtis dissimilarity calculated as 0/0 and this is Not a Number (NaN) and you also get a warning

```
2: In vegdist(wide.site, method = "bray") : missing values in results
```

The warnings are there for purpose so that you can see that your data are not suitable for the methods you use. The most natural solution is to remove the empty rows that you cannot analyse.

```
k <- rowSums(wide.site) > 0
wide.site <- wide.site[k,]
```

It is **absolutely wrong** to add constant (1) to the data. It will ruin the Bray-Curtis dissimilarity.

You may think that you want to retain the empty rows, but then you cannot use dissimilarities of community composition: there is no compositional distance if there is no composition. The `vegdist` function will handle these cases with warnings: nothing vs. anything is dissimilarity 1 (nothing in common), but nothing vs. nothing is not a number. However, then you need to use tools that can handle such results.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I am struggling with the same problem (data with many zeros) and stumbled on a [paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jembe.2005.12.017) that suggests you do exactly that (add a dummy value of 1 to allspecies), and refers to this methods as a "zero-adjusted bray-curtis coefficient". There are assumptions to be met of course, but there is a mathematical justification for doing so. I am still unsure if it is appropriate in my case but I wanted to put the information out there for others who are considering this approach. Honestly, to me the idea of removing *real* data simply because it has zeros in order to get an analysis to work seems like a grave affront to proper data analysis. Zeros sometimes have important biological meaning, as in my case, and need to be retained.